# Use ardrone_autonomy library in qtcreator

Tags: ros, include, library, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i have a problem with subscribing to ardrone/navdata, because the library ardrone_autonomy/Navdata.h can not be found. I tried to include it with this line:

```
#include "ardrone_autonomy/Navdata.h"
```

and I also tried to include it in my project- file as a file, but it did not work.
How do i include this correctly to my project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112766/use-ardrone_autonomy-library-in-qtcreator/) by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add ardrone_autonomy to your manifest dependency , that should allow you to use the header file

---

Originally posted by [evanok](https://answers.ros.org/users/11441/evanok/) with karma: 26 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1